# What is the best text option for warning messages?

Tags: alerts, textbox

I want to make three alerts for the platform that I work, when a user uploads.

One: Success

Error:

Alert:

Since my alert space is small and my PO wants large text.

I had thought of it this way: file upload successful.

Comment: What are you asking Sergio? What to write for each message? What does the user upload?

Comment: So I thought of this here for alert messages.
Success: File imported successfully
Failure: An error occurred while importing file
Wrong extension: Invalid file format
Actually, I wanted to take my assumption about, and turn it into a certainty that this force would already pass the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate it with your users, and validate if they understand, and can go ahead in the proccess.